# How to escape XML characters in TSQL before converting to XML?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml, type-conversion

I have *XML structure* which is input param for my *stored procedure*. It contains element with **&** (which is escaped in XML). When I extract that element to `VARCHAR` I receive **&** which is not valid XML character. I need to escape it, before converting to XML again. How to do that without `REPLACE`?

I have the following text: `param1=xyz&para2=dasdasdfdas&param3`. It is a part of query string. I converted it to `XML` and send it as a part of XML structure:

```
<zzz xmlns="http://example.com">
  <aaa>aaa</aaa>
  <bbb>param1=xyz&amp;para2=dasdasdfdas&amp;param3</bbb>
</zzz>
```

Inside the stored procedure I need to extract it. I do that with:

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(@XMLInput.value('declare default element namespace "http://example.com"; (zzz/bbb)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(250)'))), ''), '');
```

I after that the value contains normal text (**&**-s are not escaped - **&**).

After some processing I need to put that string inside other XML. I make:

`CAST( ... AS XML);`

Because **&**-s are not escaped I got error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `for xml path` to create XML instead of casting.

```
select @YourVariable for xml path(''), type
```

Empty string in the path expression and the absence of an alias on the returned column will give you your string back as xml.

Answer (score 4):

That is perfectly valid XML.  If you extract the `bbb` element using the `.value` method of the XML data-type, it will be de-entitised at that point, eg

[image: Results]

You can extract and add the element with no special handling or replacing, eg using the `.modify` method of the XML data-type:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<zzz xmlns="http://example.com">
  <aaa>aaa</aaa>
  <bbb>param1=xyz&amp;para2=dasdasdfdas&amp;param3</bbb>
</zzz>'

SELECT @xml [before], DATALENGTH(@xml) dl

DECLARE @b VARCHAR(100)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://example.com' )
SELECT @b = @xml.value('(zzz/bbb/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')

SELECT @b

SET @xml.modify('declare default element namespace "http://example.com"; insert element bbb { sql:variable("@b") } after (zzz/bbb)[1]')

SELECT @xml [after], DATALENGTH(@xml) dl
```